# Win 7 Media player - Win XP 11 media player - library conversion/compatibilty

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-media-player

I just bought a laptop with Win7 64 home premium installed and the default Window Media Player that comes with that edition. I have lots of CD's that I ripped onto a network drive using XP and MP 11 for XP - now I can't see most of the album information in the library in the MP included in Win7 Home Premium. Suggestions Please!

TIA

Comment: What's the file type (or types) of these music files (MP3, WMA, WAV...)? If they're MP3 or WMA then most, if not all, info should have been transferred through the tags in the music files themselves.

Comment: All WAV files. But I think I have it straightened out for the most part now. Thanks

Comment: Then that explains your issue as the WAV format has very poor tagging support. Tags of WAV songs are usually only stored in WMP's library and not in the music files themselves.

How exactly did you fix it? Other users might be interested in the solution too.

Comment: I 'fixed it' by deleting the 50 or so CD's that I did with WMP 11 from the library and the HDD and ripping them again in WMP 12 on Win 64. So it really wasn't a fix, it was a do-over. When doing that, right clicking on the disc icon and doing 'update album info' gets it right ALMOST all the time. Some old or obscure CD's it messes up or just can't find- then you have to do 'find album info' and/or do it manually.

Comment: I also made sure to uncheck all the automatic options for getting CD info from internet. I found that sometimes even after you've used find album info and done it manually, the auto options will overwrite your manual entry with the wrong info from online sources.

Comment: You might still want to convert your music files to MP3 or (possibly lossless) WMA. Otherwise, you will run into the same problem the next time you add the files to the library on a new PC.

Comment: Good idea - I haven't looked into WMA (I do need lossless) becauseit's MS proprietary, something I try to avoid. But in for such an eventuality maybe I should use it. But isn't the info stored on the HDD together with the music? I have a remote NAS RAID storage device that holds everything, so I don't think anything is stored on the PC itself.

Comment: The info _might_ have been stored in the music files if you used Update album info before the ripping started. But even then, the info in WAV files is write-once and can't be changed anymore afterwards.
A good alternative for lossless WMA is FLAC. You can install the [Xiph.org filters](http://www.xiph.org/dshow/) for playback support and [WMP Tag Plus](http://bmproductions.fixnum.org/wmptagplus/) for library and tagging support.

Comment: OK thanks - I'll have to check into this stuff. I'm a techie by trade but my music has just been on CDs all this time except for a few things that I ripped onto my MP3 player. But now technology is so cheap and sophisticated and it's a real pain to have 700 cd's floating around - so time to move to 21st century. LOL. But I need lossless - I hear the difference. MP3's actually let your hear certain parts better, but that's because they minimize/eliminate other parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Under the **Organize** menu click **Apply media information changes**, and that should force it to add all of the album info that it can find on the online db.

Comment: I think I did try that once - but I'll try it again so I can give you some points. Still getting oriented here. I did find that if I go to 'Album' view and right click 'update album info' it does seem to help sometimes - not sure if it's taking it from an online source or what's already there. Also in the XP MP there is place where you can share a library with another machine on the network - tried that and it found the machine but that didn't help. I guess if there's compatibility issues with the libraries that's useless. Couldn't find such a thing in the Win7 MP. Anyhow, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, right-clicking each album is one way to do it, but that's a grueling process. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do in the second part.

Comment: It appears to share the library but if it's not compatible that doesn't help. I also found that you can do a multi select and right click and do a bunch at once - your way is good too but I think sometimes it will be garbage from online and screw up something you loaded manually - so you have to be selective.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes that happens, but for the most part I haven't had many problems with it.